# How To Open Application And Then screenshot With python

Tags: python, pyautogui

How To Open Application And then screenshot In Python

I try with Module pyautogui, but went i openned the application, its can't screenshot, went i close the application it will screenshot

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.call("pandora.exe")
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.screenshot("ss.png")
```

Comment: is it showing any error?

Comment: no error showing

Comment: did you test with any other application? is it working for other applications?

Comment: i test 2 application, but 1 application work, 1 more is not work

Comment: i got, the app must be run as admin, but how

Comment: how run app as admin in python